# require_once(Zend/Application.php): failed to open stream- working on other computers

Tags: php, zend-framework

I just installed Zend Framework, when I try to open a website that was created with that framework I get the error below. 
 
 I know the problem is that the library is not included as I checked some other questions before... Here is what I did to try to resolve it but it's still not working. An important thing to note is that the files are working on an other computer. So it's not coming from the code.

> Warning: require_once(Zend/Application.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\data\trunk\www\public\index.php on line 68
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Application.php' (include_path='C:\data\trunk\library;;C:\data\trunk\www\application;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\data\trunk\www\public\index.php on line 68

I did a symlink between:

```
C:\data\trunk\library\ZendFramework-1.11.9\library and 
C:\data\site.local
```

I also did a symlink for:

```
C:\data\trunk\library\ZendFramework-1.11.9\extras\library and 
C:\data\site.local
```

In my index.php (C:\data\trunk\www\public):

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../library'),
realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../common'),
realpath(APPLICATION_PATH),
get_include_path(),
)));

 require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

 $application = new Zend_Application(
 APPLICATION_ENV,
 APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
  );
```

---

EDIT:

So I found a file that confirmed that I should be using Zend-1.12.3. I also found a txtfile saying " to point library files to the site.local directory. This is where the zend library is located".

I found a file in site.local 
Name: Zend
Content: link /Sites/_library/Zend-1.12.3

I found 2 files in trunk/library : 
Name: Zend
Content: link ../../site.local/Zend

Name: ZendX
 
Content: link ../../site.local/ZendX

This is my new architecture if I follow what is written:

- C:\xampp3\htdocs\mywebsite

  - trunk

    - library

      - Zend-1.12.3

        - application
      - ZendX-1.12.3

        - application
  - site.local

    - Zend-1.12.3

      - application
    - ZendX-1.12.3

      - application

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is definitely a path problem...

I can see from your paths above that the library is located in `C:\data\trunk\library\ZendFramework-1.11.9\library`, not sure about what you wanted to achieve with your symlinks here.
The class you are looking for in the code is `Zend_Application` (`Zend/Application.php`) and therefore php will be looking in all the locations defined in your `include_path` whether a `Zend/Application.php` file exist and whether it contains a class named `Zend_Application`.

If you rename the library folder from `ZendFramework-1.11.9` to `ZendFramework-1.11.9` that should be almost ok (there should not be a library folder inside of it though...). Maybe inside of the `ZendFramework-1.11.9/library` folder you have a `Zend` folder, that would be the one you need in your include path. Same thing for the extra lib (I seem to recall it mainly provides resources and ZendX libraries).

You definitely need to understand the concept of `include_path`. Do not hesitate to use `print_r(explode(';', get_include_path())); exit;` to understand what your include_path contains.
Any question come back and ask!

---

The problem clearly comes from wrong paths and include path.

As we do not know where the libraries are fetched from, I will explain using versions we can find online. **Beware:** I do not know whether the libraries you have have been edited, sometimes bad developers tend to do that... Please do a diff on your libraries and mines before interchanging them...

So we know the project is under the following document root: `C:\data\trunk\`

- C:\data\trunk\

  - www

    - application

      - ...
    - public

      - index.php
  - library

    - Zend
    - ZendX

According to your logs, `include_path='C:\data\trunk\library;;C:\data\trunk\www\application;C:\xampp\php\PEAR'`, meaning we can load any classes from `C:\data\trunk\library`.

Let's now focus on the `C:\data\trunk\library` folder.

- Zend

  - Acl
  - Application.php
  - ... (https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/tree/master/library/Zend)

You can download this library from Github for ZF 1.12.*, but according to your first message you are on 1.11, so you can retrieve packages from the official website: https://framework.zend.com/downloads/archives

Fetch the version you use, full version: https://packages.zendframework.com/releases/ZendFramework-1.11.9/ZendFramework-1.11.9.zip

Then open the zip file, and retrieve only the folders you need. You need to copy and paste `library/Zend` and `extras/library/ZendX` into your folder `C:\data\trunk\library`. That should be all you need really

Comment: So I changed where my library is and I also changed the name of the library folder. Right now the architecture is:
C:/xampp/htdocs/website/site.local/Zend-1.11.9
and in that folder there is the Application.php

And it's still not working!

Comment: I changed the name for Zend-1.11.9 because when I import my documents with SVN I get an error "external failed" "C:\xampp\htdocs\website\site.local\Zend-1.11.9"

Comment: Would you mind if I ask you a few questions in private about the installation process? I am a little bit mixed up and need some help.

Comment: The principle of this forum (and most of the similar ones you can find online) is specifically to answer publicly so it helps others as well. I will update my previous answer, but basically your problem comes from the include path. Where did you get the library from? Have you got any kind of installation documentation?

Comment: Ok I will create a new post to make sure I understand the logic of the installation.
I downloaded it from Github: https://github.com/zendframework/zf1-extras
I got some general installation documentation but not specifically for my website.

Comment: I changed my post as said before. Please do not create a new post, a single thread for a single problem is always easier to understand, so stay on this topic. As a general agreement, we ask people to understand the basic concepts (in this case the include_path) and then ask more specific questions. We are here to help but you still need to understand if we want to go past the problem!

Comment: I just edited my post according to your last edit (thank you). it' still not working but I understand more and more the architecture

Comment: It's probably fixed by now, isn't it? (I'm back from holidays)